# upload a file using bootstrap uploader

Tags: vb.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap file upload. My html code is give below

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label>Video Name:</label>
   <input class="form-control" placeholder="Video Name" id="vname" name="vname">
       </div>
    <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                        <span>Add files...</span>
                        <input type="file" name="files[]" id="fileupload1" multiple>
                    </span>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                        <span>Start upload</span>
                    </button>
```

But when i look in Server side code in Request form there is vname value but files[] is empty. Please help how to get file data in server and save it on hard disk. Thanks

Comment: I have a feeling that you declare vname but arent giving it a value when there is an upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you set the enctype attribute on the form to multipart/form-data?

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
```